# ListGrid values are not refreshing

Tags: smartgwt

I have an UI, where a main button is present. When I click on this button, I get a pop-up window which contains two ListGrids, one drop-down and one save button.

The problem is when I drag and drop something from the left ListGrid to the right one and simply close the window without saving the values. If I click on main button again, then the pop-up contains that drag-n-dropped value already present in right list grid.

Same is the case when I select some other value from the drop-down. During a change of the drop-down value, I am making a call to server and resetting the values in both the ListGrids, but this is not refreshing the values.

I am setting values with the use of Datasource. I tried `invlaidateCache()`, `AutoCacheAllData()`, `setCacheAllData()`

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

The ListGrids are being changed, and saved. You can save the state of ListGrid after clicking the main button, and if the close button is clicked - revert all changes.

That is, if I understood correctly. It would be helpful if you could define a question, which you look answering for.